# Yii Join Table Command

Tags: yii, sql-injection

I'm currently working on Yii SQL Injection. I have the following command sql command to run:

```
SELECT p.email, p.email_secret, p.verificationcode, r.name
        FROM personal p
        JOIN profile r
        ON p.email='example@example.com'
```

I have written the following code with yii:

```
        $connection=Yii::app()->db;  
        $command=$connection->createCommand();
        $command->select('p.email, p.email_secret, p.verificationcode, r.name');
        $command->from('personal p');
        $command->join('profile r', 'p.email = r.email');
        $command->where('p.email=:email', array(':email'=>'yeoh.chan1@gmail.com'));
        $rows=$command->queryAll();
```

I would like to know where this would be vulnerable SQL Injection and if so, what would be a better approach to deal with table joinings.

Answer (score 2):

Since this has no variables in it, there is no possibility for SQL injection.  However, I am guessing that you are planning to pass the email address in as a parameter, and since you have the :email parameter marker you are safe.

Just a tidbit here, you don't have to repeat `$command->` on every line.  You can write it like this:

```
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;  
    $command=$connection->createCommand();
    $command->select('p.email, p.email_secret, p.verificationcode, r.name')
        ->from('personal p')
        ->join('profile r', 'p.email = r.email')
        ->where('p.email=:email', array(':email'=>'yeoh.chan1@gmail.com'));
    $rows=$command->queryAll();
```

This works because all the statement clauses (except distinct) return the command object, and can be strung together.  If you need distinct, you can make `->setDistinct()` the last item in the chain.

Comment: But is there a better way to do it, or is this enough?

Comment: using the parameter markers and passing in an array of parameters is the correct way.